# Percentages: Matches played by a team

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A team plays $40$ matches in any year and wins $40$% of the matches. Next
>   year the team won some consecutive matches and the percentage of its
>   winning matches becomes $80$% . Find out how many matches did the team
>   win consecutively.

Does this question mean that in the next year as well the team plays $40$ matches, and they win $32$ matches consecutively which makes it $80$ % $?$

If this interpretation is not correct, then please help me understand what this question means. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does mean that. This is because it says:

> A team plays 40 matches in **any** year.

So every year, the team will play 40 matches.

What isn't clear is whether the $80%$ includes the first year or not. If it does then this problem is not solvable since it would require the team to win 48 matches which isn't possible in a 40 match season. Therefore, we would have to assume that *"becoming $80$%"* simply includes the second year alone, in which case you are right and should be 32.

Comment: The answer is 80 :(

Comment: Are you sure? The team wins 80 matches consecutively in one 40 match season??

Comment: Yes, the answer given in the book is 80.